# Monitored folder with spaces

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have used a script from the Internet which works great in my test location but, the production location has spaces in both the monitored and destination file paths. I have wrapped the destination location file path in double `"` and this is working. The same doesn't work for the monitored folder.

Example:
This works fine:

```
$folder = "C:\Users\Administrator.OMT\Documents\PowerShell\start"
```

I want this to work:

```
$folder = "C:\Users\Administrator.OMT\Documents\PowerShell\start space"
```

Comment: You need to show your code if you expect anyone to help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a double quote try using single quotes, (e.g., 'c:\test path\misc'). This will allow any special characters to be ignored.